# Can foreign pilots get a Canadian ATPL and work for a Canadian commercial airline?

Tags: student-pilot, canada, transport-canada

Can foreign pilots get a work permit for a Canadian commercial airline upon the completion of their training in Canada?

Comment: It is certainly possible that anyone might get a work permit to do any work in Canada. Are you asking if there is some automatic grant of a work permit?

Comment: @DJClayworth I am asking specifically for "airline pilots" to work as an airline pilot upon getting my licenses and 1500 flight hours, what I mean is practically speaking why would an airline sponser a foregin pilot and cost itself time and money while they can hire Canadian citizens or permanent residents?

Comment: Because after some research i found out that H1B visa (work permit in the USA) is difficult to get, so i wanted to know what is the situation in Canada for hiring foregin pilots in terms of ease/possibility

Comment: There is a whole site called [Expatriates](http://expatraites.stackexchange.com) which is all about living and working abroad.

Comment: What licenses do you already hold?

Comment: None, I am still in choosing a flight school phase, planned start date march 18'